# why does my networkx graph display no edges between the nodes?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have two lists. One of them has this data structure: in each row first element is the ID, second is the email adress.

```
     ['0', 'kvogel@politico.com']
     ['1','ababab@politico.com']
```

the Second list is a "who wrote to whom" list, in each row with the first ID-Number being the sender and the second being the recipient

```
     ['0', '4']
     ['0', '6']
     ['1', '4']
```

Btw, the brackets are not actually part of the lists. this is my jupyter notebook output. the first list has around 2000 and the second list has 40000 rows. In the code below i add the nodes - in this case the email adresses - from the first list. and then i loop through the second list and use the given IDs to create edges between the nodes.

```
    first =-1
    second =-1
    for row in idsList:
         g.add_nodes_from(row[1])
    for row in dncList:
        for i in range (len(idsList)):
            if (row[0]==idsList[i][0]):
                first=i;
            elif(row[1]==idsList[i][0]):
                second=i
        g.add_edge(idsList[first][1],idsList[second][1])
    nx.draw_networkx(g,with_labels = False, node_size = 30)
    plt.show()
```

However, i can't see the edges between the nodes. the above code produces the below graph. printing with `edges()` gives me the list of all the edges, so no problem there. what am i missing here?

[image: Graph]

Comment: Just a comment.  This for loop is hard to read because of all the indexing.  `for i in range (len(idsList)) ...`   How about doing 
`for index, id in enumerate(idsList):    
if id[0] == row[0]:
  first = index   
elif id[0] =row[0]:  
  second = index`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your graph looks currently undirected. You should change this and make it a directed graph unless you are supposed to make it undirected. that should solve it.

```
g = nx.DiGraph()
```

Comment: But why are edges not shown for undireced graphs?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with your edge generation. `sec` isn't defined for example, and `first` or `second` might be kept from a previous iteration.

If you convert your first list to a dict, you won't need a second loop. Here's a faster way to define your graph:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l1 = [ ['0', 'kvogel@politico.com'],
     ['1','ababab@politico.com'],
     ['2','c'],
     ['3','d'],
     ['4','e']
      ]

l2 = [['0', '4'],
     ['0', '2'],
     ['2', '3'],
     ['1', '3'],
     ['1', '2'],
     ['1', '4']]

addresses = dict(l1)

g = nx.Graph()
for address in addresses.values():
    g.add_node(address)

for i1, i2 in l2:
    g.add_edge(addresses[i1], addresses[i2])

nx.draw_networkx(g,with_labels = False, node_size = 30)
plt.show()
```

It outputs:
[image]

Comment: @Reti43: I converted keys to integers at first so dict comprehension were needed. Updated. Thanks!

Comment: @EricDuminil: i tried your way with my own l1 and l2, but to no avail. the graph it produced is very similar to the graph that i posted above. so still no visible edges..

Comment: @artre: Could you please post some more data, let's say 20 nodes and 100 edges? This should be more than enough to check what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code almost same to yours:

```
idsList = [ 
  ['0', 'kvogel@politico.com'],
  ['1','ababab@politico.com'],
  ['2','foo@example.com'],
  ['3','bar@example.com'],
  ['4','ALPHA@BETA.COM']
  ]
dncList = [
  ['0', '4'],
  ['2', '3'],
  ['1', '3'],
  ['1', '2'],
  ['1', '4']
  ]
g = nx.Graph()
first =-1
second =-1
for row in idsList:
      g.add_nodes_from(row[1])
for row in dncList:
    for i in range (len(idsList)):
        if (row[0]==idsList[i][0]):
            first=i;
        elif(row[1]==idsList[i][0]):
            second=i
    g.add_edge(idsList[first][1],idsList[second][1])
nx.draw_networkx(g,with_labels = True, node_size = 300, node_color='skyblue')
plt.show()
```

then got:

[image]

The solution is basically to use `add_node` instead of `add_nodes_from` like this:

```
g = nx.Graph()
for row in idsList:
  g.add_node(row[0], email=row[1])
for row in dncList:
  g.add_edge(row[0], row[1])
nx.draw_networkx(g,with_labels = True, node_size = 300, node_color='skyblue')
plt.show()
```

[image]