# graph nodes and edges drawn by the nx.draw_networkx function are not connected

Tags: python, plot, graph, networkx

The image I drew using the following code looks like this.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l1 = [ ['0', '11'],
     ['1','12'],
     ['2','13'],
     ['3','14'],
     ['4','15']]

l2 = [['0', '4'],
     ['0', '2'],
     ['2', '3'],
     ['1', '3'],
     ['1', '2'],
     ['1', '4']]

addresses = dict(l1)

g = nx.Graph()
for address in addresses.values():
    g.add_node(address)

for i1, i2 in l2:
    g.add_edge(addresses[i1], addresses[i2])

nx.draw_networkx(g,with_labels = False, node_size = 30)
plt.show()
```

[The Plot of Code Execution Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDLIt.png)

In fact, my code comes entirely from the second answer in this link:
[why does my networkx graph display no edges between the nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704535/why-does-my-networkx-graph-display-no-edges-between-the-nodes)

I think the code should be error free, after all, the respondent can run the correct experimental diagram himself. This is strange, and it seems that no one on the internet has encountered similar problems.

All nodes are displayed, but only a portion of the edges are displayed and are not connected to the nodes. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are using strings as node labels in the graph (l1) but using integers as node labels in the edges (l2). This mismatch causes the edges to be incorrectly connected or not connected at all. Check this out :)

Comment: I tried changing the character types of l1 and l2 to make them consistent. Unfortunately, the image remains the same as before, with nodes and edges not connected. This is strange, and it seems that no one on the internet has encountered similar problems. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: I am not sure but can you check the with_labels =  True?

Comment: I tried your best, but it still doesn't work. In fact, my code comes entirely from the second answer in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704535/why-does-my-networkx-graph-display-no-edges-between-the-nodes
I think the code should be error free, after all, the respondent can run the correct experimental diagram himself.

Answer (score 0):

With matplotlib 3.7.1 and networkx 3.1 it works for me.

Perhaps a package upgrade might solve the issue for you: `pip install --upgrade matplotlib networkx`

[image: network.png]